# Angular - the best approach to keep plain text

Tags: html, angular

I was wondering what is the best way to keep all your text in Angular application?

I know we could just keep it in html

```
<div>example1</div>
```

We could keep it as a variable in component

```
textForDiv = 'example2';
...
<div>{{textForDiv}}</div>
```

What is the best way to keep text and have a clean code? Let's suppose that I'm using only one language in my application.

Comment: i18n has you covert: https://angular.io/guide/i18n

Comment: for all the constants you have have separate file and maintain there

Comment: Use i18n as mentioned to prevent later refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

It depends purely on your project requirements. 
The following two cases you will encounter while developing any web application.

Case 1: The text that was displayed in the HTML is static and will not change at any time, when application is running.

In this case go with HTML

Case 2: Here the text displayed is of dynamic content and it will change based on any other value or by any API call from server.

In this case go with storing in Javascript variables

Hope it solves your query :)

Answer (score 0):

I came here looking for the same answer, so I will try to give my approach.
As said in the previous answer, if your text is dynamic, then you need to store the text in a variable and render using string interpolation (or any other available feature).

Now the thing is, if your text is static (it won't change, at least not at runtime), then. Should we always use the HTML static text variant?

Well, here arise some tradeoffs, because it is easier to declare the text directly in your HTML template, but if text grows too long, it will polute your code and make it hard to "read".

#### Then you need to decide between:

1. Using the static approach:

```html
<main>
  <section>
      <p>some static long text ....(imagine many lines)...here</p>
  </section>
  <section>
      <p>more static different long text</p>
  </section>
  <section>
      <p>some static different long text</p>
  </section>
</main>
```

2. using the so-called hybrid approach

**my.component.html**

```html
<main>
  <section *ngFor="let block of content;">
      <p>{{block}}</p>
  </section>
</main>
```

**my.component.ts**

```js
//this is not the full code, of course.

const content: string[] = [
  "some static long text ....(imagine many lines)...here",
  "more static different long text",
  "more static different long text"
]
```

**I would recommend the second approach**, but since I haven't tested if this could impact my app performance, taking into account that if the text grows too much, I will outsource the content to an asset file and load it via **get**, I leave the choice to you.

#### A more complex situation

Let's say you want to embed some link inside your long text, or use complex semantics and nested elements, or even use different styles in your text:

```html
<p>
  <!--some text-->
  <span id="ng-name">Angular</span> has many ways to render text(...).
  Among the many benefits of using <a ... >template interpolation</a>, we could mention: 
</p>
<ul>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

This is different, now you can't use just `ngFor` for rendering text, since it won't be able to handle such a complex structure.

Either you choose the static way or use a feature called **content projection** (Check the [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/content-projection) for more details).

Here, another tradeoff arises again, since you must decide if the problem deserves the complexity added by the content projection feature, or you can manage with a static approach

Then, I would recommend the "simple is better" principle, and add more complexity just if it is strictly needed. Fancier solutions aren't necessarily the best ones.

Hope you find it useful.